# Jdbc error after update java 8

Tags: mysql, jdbc, java-8, tomcat7

I have a server linux Ubuntu (14.04.4) with Tomcat and Java in it.

I recently upgraded Java from 7 to 8 (leaving Tomcat 7)
this is the situation
[image: tomcat version.sh]

[image: java -version]

my web application starts but throws an exception during the db connection

```
Jul 11, 2016 3:41:19 PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
```

this is the connection URL: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/`

NOTE 1: mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar is in tomcat lib

NOTE 2: I tried to put mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar even in WEB-INF/lib

NOTE 3: the same application with the same configuration of Tomcat and Java works fine in my local pc.

UPDATE:

here the configuration:

```
PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();

        p.setRemoveAbandoned(Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperties().getProperty(pathContestoString+"db.removeAbandoned")));
        p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(Integer.parseInt(System.getProperties().getProperty(pathContestoString+"db.removeAbandonedTimeout")));
        p.setLogAbandoned(Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperties().getProperty(pathContestoString+"db.logAbandoned")));
        p.setMaxActive(Integer.parseInt(System.getProperties().getProperty(pathContestoString+"db.maxActive")));
        p.setMaxIdle(Integer.parseInt(System.getProperties().getProperty(pathContestoString+"db.maxIdle")));
        p.setMaxWait(Integer.parseInt(System.getProperties().getProperty(pathContestoString+"db.maxWait")));
        p.setUsername(System.getProperties().getProperty(pathContestoString+"db.user"));
        p.setPassword(System.getProperties().getProperty(pathContestoString+"db.pwd"));
        p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        p.setUrl(System.getProperties().getProperty(pathContestoString+"db.url")+System.getProperties().getProperty(pathContestoString+"db.dbname")+"?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;ssl=true");

        // factory?
        // closeMethod?
        p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
```

App.properties:

```
db.user=myUser
db.pwd=myPwd
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
db.dbname=myDbName
db.maxActive=50
db.maxIdle=30
db.maxWait=50000
db.removeAbandoned=true
db.removeAbandonedTimeout=20
db.logAbandoned=true
```

Comment: looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288947/tomcat-unable-to-create-initial-connections-of-pool check if your configuration is proper

Comment: @Tinki This question is not answered.

Comment: yes, but it demonstrates proper configuration, which should be reflected in your case. Basing on this example simply check if you are not missing anything

Comment: My conf is quite different. I updated the question with the details